# accept specific characters in textbox

Tags: javascript, textbox

I have textbox, it allows only one character to enter.

- i need to allow only (**C** or **D**) letters to accept.
- backspace and Enter keys can be allowed

i need java script function for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this problem.

```js
 $('#txtChk').on('input', function(evt) {
        $(this).val(function(_, val) {
            if (val.toUpperCase() == 'C' || val.toUpperCase() == 'D') {
                return val.toUpperCase();
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    below text box allows only C or D letters<br/><br/>
 <input type="textbox" id="txtChk">
    
  </body>
 </html>
```